# what is the correct way to validate form with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

should i put "submit" instead "form_name" in the last block of code? what is the correct way? 
thanks!

```
function check() {
    var title = document.getElementById("title");
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    if (title == "") {
        alert("title is required");
        return false;
    }
    if (content == "") {
        alert("content is required");
        return false;
    }
    var submit = document.getElementById("form_name");
    submit.submit();
}
```

this is my form

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="form_name" name="form_name">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
    <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="return check();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `if (title == "")` { <-- You are checking that a DOM element is equal to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

First you are selecting an element and acting like it is the value

```
var title = document.getElementById("title");  <-- DOM element
if (title == "") { <-- checking the DOM against a string.
```

You should be using .value to get what was entered.

Next you are submitting the form.... but you clicked on a submit button inside of the form so that will submit the form. So that is not needed.

```
function check() {
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var content = document.getElementById("content").value;
    if (!title.trim().length) {
        alert("title is required");
        return false;
    else if (!content.trim().length) {
        alert("content is required");
        return false;
    }
    return true
}
```

And never name anything submit, it just leads to problems.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i wanted to write title.value == "" and content.value == ""

Comment: so, can i use just return true instead submit variable that i created?

Comment: Did you try to code? Yes you return true and do not submit the form inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

In most recent browsers you have more power to use

```js
function myFunction() {
    var inpObj = document.getElementById("id1");
    if (inpObj.checkValidity() == false) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="id1" type="number" min="100" max="300" required>
<button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp